# restore_current_blog() vs switch_to_blog()

Tags: multisite

After every instance of [`switch_to_blog()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5.1/wp-includes/ms-blogs.php#L484) you should call [`restore_current_blog()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5.1/wp-includes/ms-blogs.php#L556) to restore the current (actually, previous) blog.

But if you're looping through two or more blogs and calling `switch_to_blog()` on each, is there any reason *not* to use an additional `switch_to_blog()` at the end of the loop to switch to the original blog rather than calling `restore_current_blog()` at each pass.

E.g.

Why not:

```
 $original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
 foreach( $blog_ids as $blog_id ){
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    //Do stuff
 }
 switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id );
```

instead of:

```
 foreach( $blog_ids as $blog_id ){
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    //Do stuff
    restore_current_blog_id();
 }
```

Comment: Now I understand this, thanks for correcting that answer of mine ;) Am revising everything.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After every instance of `switch_to_blog()` you **need** to call `restore_current_blog()` otherwise WP will think it is in a "switched" mode and can potentially return incorrect data.

If you view the source code for both functions you will see those functions push/pop data into a global called `$GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack']`.  If you do not call `restore_current_blog()` after every `switch_to_blog()`, `$GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack']` will be non-empty.  If `$GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack']` is non-empty WP thinks it is in a switched mode, even if you switched back to the original blog using `switch_to_blog()`.  The switched mode function is [`ms_is_switched()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.7.1/wp-includes/ms-blogs.php#L608) and it affects [`wp_upload_dir()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.7.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L1558).  If `wp_upload_dir()` thinks it is in a switched mode, it can return data that is incorrect. `wp_upload_dir()` builds URLs for the site, so it is a very critical function.

This is the correct use:

```
 foreach( $blog_ids as $blog_id ){
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    //Do stuff
    restore_current_blog();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've not had chance to work through the soup of constants & logic that `wp_upload_dir()` employs to generate urls, but I shall take your word that this does indeed result in buggy behaviour. In any case, the existence of `ms_is_switched()` means my alternative approach results in the function not behaving as expected and could break plug-ins as well as core. Thanks

Comment: If this is true, then the Codex page for [`restore_current_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog) needs an update, since it says that for multiple switches, one need only save the current `$blog_id` and then use multiple `switch_to_blog()` calls.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to run over multiple blogs there is no need to restore the previous blog each time. The only thing that grows is `$GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack']` – an array with blog IDs, nothing to worry about.

But keep in mind, `restore_current_blog()` **will not work ( ! ! ! )** anymore after the second switch, because it uses the previous blog – which is not the *first* blog then. So store the first blog ID, and call …

```
switch_to_blog( $first_blog_id ); 
unset ( $GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack'] );
$GLOBALS['switched'] = false;
```

… instead of `restore_current_blog()` when you are done. The global variables must be reset, or you will run into the issues mentioned by @user42826.

The performance impact is huge. I’ve run some tests on a local installation with 12 sites:

```
$sites = wp_get_sites();

print '<pre>' . count( $sites ) . " sites\n";

timer_start();

print 'With restore_current_blog():    ';

foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
    switch_to_blog( $site[ 'blog_id' ] );
    restore_current_blog();
}

timer_stop( 1, 9 );

print "\nWithout restore_current_blog(): ";

timer_start();

$current_site = get_current_blog_id();

foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
    switch_to_blog( $site[ 'blog_id' ] );
}

switch_to_blog( $current_site );
$GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack'] = array();
$GLOBALS['switched']           = FALSE;

timer_stop( 1, 9 );

print '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
12 sites
With restore_current_blog():    0.010648012
Without restore_current_blog(): 0.005203962
```

Using `restore_current_blog()` after each switch doubles the time that is needed just for switching.

Comment: Thought there wasn't any reason not to. Was confused why `restore_current_blog()` didn't just retrive the previous blog ID and call `switch_to_blog()` - a brief look at the code source and it seems there's a bit of code duplication...

Comment: great info. Didn´t know that . Maybe `restore_current_blog()` should have switched the name to `restore_previous_blog()`. or maybe change the whole function´s own functionality to operate as a real `restore_main_blog()`. trac material.

Comment: One more thing needs to be set as well: `$GLOBALS['switched'] = false;`. Although the function `ms_is_switched()` do check for `$GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack']` but this is introduced since 3.5 and some plugins are still using `$GLOBALS['switched']` to see if WP is in switched mode or not.

Comment: I don't think modifying the globals directly is a good idea, because you're coupling your code to Core's internals, which isn't future-proof. It's better to use the API properly.

Comment: @IanDunn Just for the record: `switch_to_blog()` is a very limited (broken) API anyway. If WordPress ever fixes _that_, we have to refactor our code anyway. And WordPress will never give up its beloved globals.

Comment: advice related to this that messes up blog ID..... NEVER call a variable `$blog_id` or you will mess up everything!

Comment: @JacobRaccuia Nope, just don't create global variables. Then you can use every name you want.

Comment: @toscho that's what I thought, but I had set a variable higher up on the page called `$blog_id = 2` and it messed up my loop and caused `get_current_blog_id` to return 2 instead of 1 (when I was on 1).  I fixed it by changing my `$blog_id` to `$blogID`.   The only reason I knew to do this was because I used to loop through a list `foreach($post as $blog_id => $v)` and sending `$blog_id` into `switch_to_blog()` doesn't work either.

Comment: @IanDunn `I don't think modifying the globals directly is a good idea`, don't tell that to wp core developers ;)

Comment: I think that you should mention that you need to back up and restore the globals instead of just resetting them if you don't know whether or not WordPress could have already been switched to another blog before you start.

Comment: @J.D. Of course, you need to be context aware. In the case of an already switched state you might have even to maintain the correct index of the stack. I would probably search for a way to avoid that. On the other hand, this is WordPress, so there might be no other way …

Comment: @toscho maybe it's good idea if you do this: http://pastebin.com/raw/R2H6N0t3  and execute only once after loop  (so, there will be no need to run extra functions, i.e. `get_current_blog_id` before the loops )

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @toscho answer. This request in queue of WP - see updates [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37958).  Till that is fixed in WP, if anyone desperately wants to use standard `restore_current_blog()`, then here is another method (please correct if I am wrong):

make your function, i.e.

```
function restore_original_blog_X(){

    if(!empty(($GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack'][0])){
        $GLOBALS['blog_id']= $GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack'][0];
        $GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack'] = array($GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack'][0]);
        restore_current_blog();
    }

}
```

and execute only once when you finish your multiple switches. 
(more: [**wp-includes/ms-blogs.php**](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6.1/src/wp-includes/ms-blogs.php#L0) )