# Get posts from sites in Multisite?

Tags: categories, multisite, query-posts

I'm trying to pull multiple sites posts. For example, I can pull out a single site
posts by a category and total posts 10.

But I'm trying to pull out both posts from two separate Multisite blogs 1 & 2. But only blog 1 works. Also, I want to pull out another category from blog 1 and blog 2 by another category. How can I achieve this?

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
<?php
global $switched;
switch_to_blog(1,2); //switched to 1 & 2 but only 1 working

// Get latest Post
$latest_posts = get_posts('&cat=64&showposts=10');
$cnt =0;?> 
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($latest_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>"><?php echo  short_title('...', 7); ?></a>
    </li>                                
<?php endforeach ; ?>

<?php restore_current_blog(); //switched back to main site ?>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The WordPress function `switch_to_blog()` expects an integer as an input parameter. You can read more about it in the Codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog

Please try this kind of structure instead:

```
// Get the current blog id
$original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id(); 

// All the blog_id's to loop through
$bids = array( 1, 2 ); 

foreach( $bids as $bid )
{
    // Switch to the blog with the blog_id $bid
    switch_to_blog( $bid ); 

    // ... your code for each blog ...
}

// Switch back to the current blog
switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id );
```

### Update:

If you want to fetch posts from different categories for each blog, you can use for example:

```
// Get current blog
$original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id(); 

// Setup a category slug for each blog id, you want to loop through - EDIT
$catslug_per_blog_id = array( 
    1 => 'video',
    4 => 'news' 
); 

foreach( $catslug_per_blog_id as $bid => $catslug )
{
    // Switch to the blog with the blog id $bid
    switch_to_blog( $bid ); 

    // ... your code for each blog ...
    $myposts = get_posts( 
        array( 
            'category_name'  => $catslug,
            'posts_per_page' => 10, 
        )
    );
    // ... etc
}

// Switch back to the current blog
switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id );
```

### Example:

Here is an example that allows you to use template tags (this works on my multisite install):

```
// Get current blog
$original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

// Setup a category for each blog id you want to loop through - EDIT
$catslug_per_blog_id = array( 
    1 => 'video',
    4 => 'news' 
); 

foreach( $catslug_per_blog_id as $bid => $catslug )
{
    //Switch to the blog with the blog id $bid
    switch_to_blog( $bid ); 

    // Get posts for each blog
    $myposts = get_posts( 
        array( 
            'category_name'  => $catslug,
            'posts_per_page' => 2, 
        )
    );

    // Skip a blog if no posts are found
    if( empty( $myposts ) )
        continue;

    // Loop for each blog
    $li = '';
    global $post;
    foreach( $myposts as $post )
    {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        $li .= the_title(
            $before = sprintf( '<li><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),
            $after  = '</a></li>',
            $echo   = false
        );
    }

    // Print for each blog
    printf(
        '<h2>%s (%s)</h2><ul>%s</ul>',
        esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ),
        esc_html( $catslug ),
        $li  
    );
}

// Switch back to the current blog
switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id ); 

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Here's a demo screenshot for our above example with site 1 named *Beethoven* and site 4 named *Bach*:

[image: demo]

PS: Thanks to @brasofilo providing the [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89113/restore-current-blog-vs-switch-to-blog) that clarifies my misunderstanding of the `restore_current_blog()` ;-)

PPS: Thanks to @ChristineCooper for sharing the following comment:

> Just a friendly warning. Make sure to not set your original blog id to
>   variable `$blog_id` -- this is because during the `switch_to_blog()`
>   process, `$blog_id` will be overriden by the core function, meaning what
>   when you try to switch back to the original blog, you will end up with
>   switching to the last one you looped through. A little bit of a
>   mind-puzzle. :)

Comment: here's how i load my posts http://pastie.org/7827649 how can i implement that into this also like i mention by both blog ids but each blog id by specific category  blog 1 will have category videos & the blog 2 will have the category news  also get a total posts of 10 limit.

Comment: I updated the answer to support different categories.

Comment: Check this: [restore_current_blog() vs switch_to_blog()](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/89113/12615)

Comment: @brasofilo, many thanks for the link, this changes my view on `restore_current_blog()` ;-)

Comment: Stephen Harris did the same for me :)

Comment: I will try to pass it on to my fellow wp users ;-)

Comment: im still encountering an issue, it just shows one post only on the original multisite blog thats all heres how i did it http://pastie.org/7831263

Comment: need some help anyone?..

Comment: Try the simple example I added to the answer, and make sure your blogs and categories are correct. If that works, then you should be able to expand it to your needs.

Comment: in your pastie version nr 2, your code should be inside the foreach loop where I marked `// ... etc`

Comment: ps: updated the example again, so you can use template tags like `the_title()` instead of `$post->post_title` ;-) I hope I have given you enough info so you can finish your project.

Comment: thanks ill let you know if it worked thanks for your amazing help :D

Comment: ok great, good luck ;-)

Comment: well look, the issue everything displays smooth but it displays everything in list you know the way i posted it in my pastie thats the way i want it because just putting title and all that its a bit complicated for me im not much knowledgeable, is there any way that can be accomplish just the simple way i had it, is there a way i can keep it like this? http://pastie.org/7896095 sorry for being a bother i hope you understand

Comment: Replace `foreach($rightbox as $post)` with `foreach($posts as $post)` in your pastie.

Comment: i get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in the index.php so i just added that code in the index.php by it self and i get that error heres the update version http://pastie.org/7896699

Comment: can someone help me, solve this?..

Comment: Just a friendly warning. Make sure to not set your original blog id to variable $blog_id -- this is because during the switch_to_blog() process, $blog_id will be overriden by the core function, meaning what when you try to switch back to the original blog, you will end up with switching to the last one you looped through. A little bit of a mind-puzzle. :)

Comment: thanks for sharing that info @ChristineCooper. It looks like I used `$original_blog_id` here to avoid overriding `$blog_id` ;-)

Comment: Hope it's ok that I added your comment to the updated answer @ChristineCooper

Comment: Hi! I would like to ask, how do i implement in order to make it work? Is it put this code in my theme or put into functions.php? Thank you!

Comment: See my answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307040/wp-rest-api-multisite-get-posts-from-all-sites/307051#307051

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at it. I have another issue which hasn't been fixed yet as no answer was given. Can you help it out? I really need a solution on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code in my "Multisite Post Reader" plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-post-reader/ . It uses the technique in the other answer to loop through the posts.  I also have plugins that do the same thing for images.

Since it is an open-source code, you are welcome to wander through the code and use pieces of it for your own use. (Some of the code is modified from open-source code I found.)