# Displaying All Posts of a Custom Post Type in Wordpress Multisite Backend

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, multisite

I have been looking around all day for an answer, and I'll post a link that I thought might work, and didn't end up panning out.

I want to be able to make a backend menu page on my Wordpress Multisite that displays a list of all my posts from every site of the post type "game" along with various custom fields that go with that post type.

Here's the link I have found and what happened with it:

[Other Stack Exchange question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98965/get-posts-from-sites-in-multisite/%22Link%20to%20other%20Stack%20Exchange%20Question%22)

First off, this does not account for my need to display custom post types and custom fields. I'm not exactly great with code, might I add, but I tinkered and tinkered with this and couldn't get it to do what I needed it to do.

Anybody got a suggestion?

EDIT: Also this I'm pretty sure only works on the front end, I need something for the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a similar plugin to display all pictures from all sites. Couldn't find one. Ended up writing my own (Multisite Media Display). Then modified that one for another plugin to display all posts (Multisite Post Reader). You can find that one here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-post-reader/ .

There isn't an option to display posts of a particular type, but wouldn't be hard to add.

Since my plugin is open source, you might find some useful techniques in the plugin code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I'll check your plugin out!

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please click on the checkmark next to it. Glad to help...most of the initial code in the plugins came from various answers here, but it took a while to put it all together.
If one of the plugins helps, great. If there is a feature that is needed, let me know via the plugin support page. (And, a nice review of the plugin is also appreciated, but not required.)