# WP_Query on different site in a multisite setup

Tags: wp-query, multisite

I am trying to retrieve search results from one multi-site site ("Staffsite" - id: `2`) and display them alongside the search results on another site that's part of the multi-site setup ("Flagship" - id: `1`). I currently have the following code in `search.php` on Flagship:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'staff',
    's'         => get_search_query(),
);

switch_to_blog( 2 ); // switch to Staffsite

$staffsite_query = new WP_Query( $args );

var_dump( $staffsite_query->post_count ); // 0

// Do something with post data

restore_current_blog(); // return to Flagship
```

The query works as expected when used in a template on Staffsite (replacing  `get_search_query()` with an actual value), returning all the relevant posts, but does not work when used from a template on Flagship in combination with `switch_to_blog()`.

For what reason does this not work?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a `switch_to_network()` that's the equivalent of `switch_to_blog()`. You *might* find what you need in the [WP Multi Network](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/) plugin.

Comment: @PatJ apologies, wrong terminology on my part. The sites are part of a multisite setup, not a multi-network setup.

Comment: Is the `staff` post type defined in a plugin? If so, and the plugin is only activated on blog 2, then its code won't be loaded on a request for blog 1, even when you use `switch_to_blog`, so it won't recognize the post type in the query.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative option could be using the [Rest API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/):

**Example (post):**

Search for *Jane Doe* in posts:

```
https://example.com/staffsite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?search=jane+doe
```

**Example (custom post types):**

If the *public* and *searchable* custom post type (e.g. `staff`) has `show_in_rest` set to `true` then we can search for *Jane Doe* in staff posts:

```
https://example.com/staffsite/wp-json/wp/v2/staff/?search=jane+doe
```

ps: Somewhat related, if you want to create your own route, using data from multiple sites in the network: [WP REST API - Multisite - get posts from all sites](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307040/wp-rest-api-multisite-get-posts-from-all-sites/307051#307051)