# Woocommerce Multisite global search how to mod ajax function?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, search, globals

I created an installation of my multisite ecommerce to differentiate the men's and women's departments. Often, however, it happens that in the men's department they do research related to women's articles or vice versa. Consequently, my site says it cannot find an article, obviously it is not so.
How can I implement a global search function? I tried with switch_to_blog on this function that I paste, unfortunately I can't make it go. Could anyone help me out?
This is code i tried...but DIE does it stop and work only on site 1...any ideas?
Thanks in advance

```
 switch_to_blog(1);
    $results = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'basel_ajax_search_args', $query_args ) );

    if ( basel_get_opt( 'relevanssi_search' ) && function_exists( 'relevanssi_do_query' ) ) {
        relevanssi_do_query( $results );
    }

    $suggestions = array();

    if ( $results->have_posts() ) {

        if ( $post_type == 'product' && basel_woocommerce_installed() ) {
            $factory = new WC_Product_Factory();
        }

        while ( $results->have_posts() ) {
            $results->the_post();

            if ( $post_type == 'product' && basel_woocommerce_installed() ) {
                $product = $factory->get_product( get_the_ID() );

                $suggestions[] = array(
                    'value' => get_the_title(),
                    'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                    'price' => $product->get_price_html(),
                    'thumbnail' => $product->get_image(),
                    'sku' => $product->get_sku() ? esc_html__( 'SKU:', 'basel' ) . ' ' . $product->get_sku() : '',
                );
            } else {
                $suggestions[] = array(
                    'value' => get_the_title(),
                    'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                    'thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'medium', '' ),
                );
            }
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
        restore_current_blog();
    } else {
        $suggestions[] = array(
            'value' => ( $post_type == 'product' ) ? esc_html__( 'No products found', 'basel' ) : esc_html__( 'No posts found', 'basel' ),
            'no_found' => true,
            'permalink' => ''
        );
    }

    switch_to_blog(2);
    $results = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'basel_ajax_search_args', $query_args ) );

    if ( basel_get_opt( 'relevanssi_search' ) && function_exists( 'relevanssi_do_query' ) ) {
        relevanssi_do_query( $results );
    }

    //$suggestions = array();

    if ( $results->have_posts() ) {

        if ( $post_type == 'product' && basel_woocommerce_installed() ) {
            $factory = new WC_Product_Factory();
        }

        while ( $results->have_posts() ) {
            $results->the_post();

            if ( $post_type == 'product' && basel_woocommerce_installed() ) {
                $product = $factory->get_product( get_the_ID() );

                $suggestions[] = array(
                    'value' => get_the_title(),
                    'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                    'price' => $product->get_price_html(),
                    'thumbnail' => $product->get_image(),
                    'sku' => $product->get_sku() ? esc_html__( 'SKU:', 'basel' ) . ' ' . $product->get_sku() : '',
                );
            } else {
                $suggestions[] = array(
                    'value' => get_the_title(),
                    'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                    'thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'medium', '' ),
                );
            }
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
        restore_current_blog();
    } else {
        $suggestions[] = array(
            'value' => ( $post_type == 'product' ) ? esc_html__( 'No products found', 'basel' ) : esc_html__( 'No posts found', 'basel' ),
            'no_found' => true,
            'permalink' => ''
        );
    }

     //$my_array2 = array('suggestions' => $suggestions);
     //$my_array1 = array('suggestions' => $suggestions1);
     //$res = array_merge($my_array2, $my_array1); 
    // echo json_encode($res);
    echo json_encode(array('suggestions' => $suggestions));

die(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

New in stackexchange, I cannot comment until I had 50 reputation.

We are in the same theme developer. I found this [topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/314483/182745) can help you. I am testing it -  WooCommerce multisite global search. But both site was newly installed with same product data (name, price, same product category, same theme). You may try it.

**OPTION 1**

before this line

```
$results = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'basel_ajax_search_args', $query_args ) );
```

Add

```
// in this variable you can pass all the blog IDs you would like to display posts from
$blog_ids = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );

foreach( $blog_ids as $id ) {

    switch_to_blog( $id );
```

**And**

after this line

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Add

```
        restore_current_blog();
```

**And**

after this 2 line

```
die();

}
```

Add

}

Try it with local host or Staging **OR** Backup your website before try.

I am trying it in my theme's search.php

```
/**
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Ajax search
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_init_search_by_sku' ) ) {
    function woodmart_init_search_by_sku() {
        if ( apply_filters( 'woodmart_search_by_sku', woodmart_get_opt( 'search_by_sku' ) ) && woodmart_woocommerce_installed() ) {
            add_filter( 'posts_search', 'woodmart_product_search_sku', 9 );
        }
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'woodmart_init_search_by_sku', 10 );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_ajax_suggestions' ) ) {
    function woodmart_ajax_suggestions() {

        $allowed_types = array( 'post', 'product', 'portfolio' );
        $post_type = 'product';

        if ( apply_filters( 'woodmart_search_by_sku', woodmart_get_opt( 'search_by_sku' ) ) && woodmart_woocommerce_installed() ) {
            add_filter( 'posts_search', 'woodmart_product_ajax_search_sku', 10 );
        }

        $query_args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_type'      => $post_type,
            'no_found_rows'  => 1,
        );

        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) && in_array( $_REQUEST['post_type'], $allowed_types ) ) {
            $post_type = strip_tags( $_REQUEST['post_type'] );
            $query_args['post_type'] = $post_type;
        }

        if ( $post_type == 'product' && woodmart_woocommerce_installed() ) {

            $product_visibility_term_ids = wc_get_product_visibility_term_ids();
            $query_args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                'field'    => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                'terms'    => $product_visibility_term_ids['exclude-from-search'],
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            );

            if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['product_cat'] ) ) {
                $query_args['product_cat'] = strip_tags( $_REQUEST['product_cat'] );
            }
        }

        if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items' ) && $post_type == 'product' ) {
            $query_args['meta_query'][] = array( 'key' => '_stock_status', 'value' => 'outofstock', 'compare' => 'NOT IN' );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['query'] ) ) {
            $query_args['s'] = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['query'] );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['number'] ) ) {
            $query_args['posts_per_page'] = (int) $_REQUEST['number'];
        }

        $blog_ids = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 );

        foreach( $blog_ids as $id ) {

            switch_to_blog( $id );


        $results = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woodmart_ajax_search_args', $query_args ) );

        if ( woodmart_get_opt( 'relevanssi_search' ) && function_exists( 'relevanssi_do_query' ) ) {
            relevanssi_do_query( $results );
        }

        $suggestions = array();

        if ( $results->have_posts() ) {

            if ( $post_type == 'product' && woodmart_woocommerce_installed() ) {
                $factory = new WC_Product_Factory();
            }

            while ( $results->have_posts() ) {
                $results->the_post();

                if ( $post_type == 'product' && woodmart_woocommerce_installed() ) {
                    $product = $factory->get_product( get_the_ID() );

                    $suggestions[] = array(
                        'value' => html_entity_decode( get_the_title() ),
                        'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                        'price' => $product->get_price_html(),
                        'thumbnail' => $product->get_image(),
                        'sku' => $product->get_sku() ? esc_html__( 'SKU:', 'woodmart' ) . ' ' . $product->get_sku() : '',
                    );
                } else {
                    $suggestions[] = array(
                        'value' => html_entity_decode( get_the_title() ),
                        'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                        'thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'medium', '' ),
                    );
                }
            }

            wp_reset_postdata();

                restore_current_blog();

        } else {
            $suggestions[] = array(
                'value' => ( $post_type == 'product' ) ? esc_html__( 'No products found', 'woodmart' ) : esc_html__( 'No posts found', 'woodmart' ),
                'no_found' => true,
                'permalink' => ''
            );
        }

        if ( woodmart_get_opt( 'enqueue_posts_results' ) && 'post' !== $post_type ) {
            $post_suggestions = woodmart_get_post_suggestions();
            $suggestions = array_merge( $suggestions, $post_suggestions );
        }

        echo json_encode( array(
            'suggestions' => $suggestions,
        ) );

        die();
    }
    }

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_woodmart_ajax_search', 'woodmart_ajax_suggestions', 10 );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woodmart_ajax_search', 'woodmart_ajax_suggestions', 10 );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_get_post_suggestions' ) ) {
    function woodmart_get_post_suggestions() {
        $query_args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_type'      => 'post',
            'no_found_rows'  => 1,
        );

        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['query'] ) ) {
            $query_args['s'] = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['query'] );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['number'] ) ) {
            $query_args['posts_per_page'] = (int) $_REQUEST['number'];
        }

        $blog_ids = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 );

        foreach( $blog_ids as $id ) {

            switch_to_blog( $id );


        $results = new WP_Query( $query_args );
        $suggestions = array();

        if ( $results->have_posts() ) {

            $suggestions[] = array(
                'value' => '',
                'divider' => esc_html__( 'Results from blog', 'woodmart' ),
            );

            while ( $results->have_posts() ) {
                $results->the_post();

                $suggestions[] = array(
                    'value' => html_entity_decode( get_the_title() ),
                    'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                    'thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'medium', '' ),
                );
            }

            wp_reset_postdata();

                restore_current_blog();

                }

        }

        return $suggestions;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_product_search_sku' ) ) {
    function woodmart_product_search_sku( $where, $class = false ) {
        global $pagenow, $wpdb, $wp;

        $type = array('product', 'jam');

        if ( ( is_admin() ) //if ((is_admin() && 'edit.php' != $pagenow) 
                || !is_search()  
                || !isset( $wp->query_vars['s'] ) 
                //post_types can also be arrays..
                || (isset( $wp->query_vars['post_type'] ) && 'product' != $wp->query_vars['post_type'] )
                || (isset( $wp->query_vars['post_type'] ) && is_array( $wp->query_vars['post_type'] ) && !in_array( 'product', $wp->query_vars['post_type'] ) ) 
                ) {
            return $where;
        }

        $s = $wp->query_vars['s'];

        //WC 3.6.0
        if ( function_exists( 'WC' ) && version_compare( WC()->version, '3.6.0', '<' ) ) {
            return woodmart_sku_search_query( $where, $s );
        } else {
            return woodmart_sku_search_query_new( $where, $s );
        }
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_product_ajax_search_sku' ) ) {
    function woodmart_product_ajax_search_sku( $where ) {
        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['query'] ) ) {
            $s = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['query'] );

            //WC 3.6.0
            if ( function_exists( 'WC' ) && version_compare( WC()->version, '3.6.0', '<' ) ) {
                return woodmart_sku_search_query( $where, $s );
            } else {
                return woodmart_sku_search_query_new( $where, $s );
            }
        }

        return $where;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_sku_search_query' ) ) {
    function woodmart_sku_search_query( $where, $s ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $search_ids = array();
        $terms = explode( ',', $s );

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            //Include the search by id if admin area.
            if ( is_admin() && is_numeric( $term ) ) {
                $search_ids[] = $term;
            }
            // search for variations with a matching sku and return the parent.

            $sku_to_parent_id = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT p.post_parent as post_id FROM {$wpdb->posts} as p join {$wpdb->postmeta} pm on p.ID = pm.post_id and pm.meta_key='_sku' and pm.meta_value LIKE '%%%s%%' where p.post_parent <> 0 group by p.post_parent", wc_clean( $term ) ) );

            //Search for a regular product that matches the sku.
            $sku_to_id = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value LIKE '%%%s%%';", wc_clean( $term ) ) );

            $search_ids = array_merge( $search_ids, $sku_to_id, $sku_to_parent_id );
        }

        $search_ids = array_filter( array_map( 'absint', $search_ids ) );

        if ( sizeof( $search_ids ) > 0 ) {
            $where = str_replace( ')))', ") OR ({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $search_ids ) . "))))", $where );
        }

        #remove_filters_for_anonymous_class('posts_search', 'WC_Admin_Post_Types', 'product_search', 10);
        return $where;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_sku_search_query_new' ) ) {
    function woodmart_sku_search_query_new( $where, $s ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $search_ids = array();
        $terms = explode( ',', $s );

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            //Include the search by id if admin area.
            if ( is_admin() && is_numeric( $term ) ) {
                $search_ids[] = $term;
            }
            // search for variations with a matching sku and return the parent.

            $sku_to_parent_id = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT p.post_parent as post_id FROM {$wpdb->posts} as p join {$wpdb->wc_product_meta_lookup} ml on p.ID = ml.product_id and ml.sku LIKE '%%%s%%' where p.post_parent <> 0 group by p.post_parent", wc_clean( $term ) ) );

            //Search for a regular product that matches the sku.
            $sku_to_id = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT product_id FROM {$wpdb->wc_product_meta_lookup} WHERE sku LIKE '%%%s%%';", wc_clean( $term ) ) );

            $search_ids = array_merge( $search_ids, $sku_to_id, $sku_to_parent_id );
        }

        $search_ids = array_filter( array_map( 'absint', $search_ids ) );

        if ( sizeof( $search_ids ) > 0 ) {
            $where = str_replace( ')))', ") OR ({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $search_ids ) . "))))", $where );
        }

        #remove_filters_for_anonymous_class('posts_search', 'WC_Admin_Post_Types', 'product_search', 10);
        return $where;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_rlv_index_variation_skus' ) ) {
    function woodmart_rlv_index_variation_skus( $content, $post ) {
        if ( ! woodmart_get_opt( 'search_by_sku' ) || ! woodmart_get_opt( 'relevanssi_search' ) || ! function_exists( 'relevanssi_do_query' ) ) {
            return $content;
        }

        if ( $post->post_type == 'product' ) {

            $args = array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'product_variation', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
            $variations = get_posts( $args );
            if ( !empty( $variations)) {
                foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
                    $sku = get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_sku', true );
                    $content .= " $sku";
                }
            }
        }

        return $content;
    }

    add_filter( 'relevanssi_content_to_index', 'woodmart_rlv_index_variation_skus', 10, 2 );
}
```

**OPTION 2**

[Premium Plugin](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/search-across-wp-multisite.html)

Hope help ^.^

Please notice me if you success.

Comment: If I remove the blog_id 1, the site1 can search the site2.

Comment: Hi I tried, if I remove the blog_id 1, the site1 can ajax search the site2, but the search page (press ENTER, but never click the ajax search result) remained the same site.

Comment: yes if i remove site 1 site 2 only works...the function exit on DIE() there's the problem. On cycle forach when it reach die() function ends to work...but without does not work

Comment: @VitoSantimone Noted, I haven't stop trying and error, to found the solution for me and you too. Thanks! keep in touch.

Comment: @WhatchTeller me too!!

Comment: i found problem! is in that lines  echo json_encode( array(
   'suggestions' => $suggestions1
  ) ); infact, i deleted cycle foreach and manually added blog 1 and blog 2. so 2 suggestions, but only one can work! So solution is to make suggestions work for the other site!

Comment: Thanks for hint up! will try it. ^.^

Comment: This is the working solution, you need to merge 2 arrays to work! So after cycle forach just: $my_array1 = array('suggestions' => $suggestions);
         $my_array2 = array('suggestions' => $suggestions1);
         $res = array_merge($my_array1, $my_array2); 
         echo json_encode($res);

Comment: Hi @VitoSantimone, I lost..... ^.^ to make me more understand it, you can post your answer (edit you code with solution) for me to follow. Thousand Thanks!

Comment: @VitoSantimone I tried, but i cannot make it work, may be i edit it in wrong line in the code. Can you post your answer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @VitoSantimone  Need you help!

Comment: Sorry for delay! Monday i will post perfect functionant PHP!

Comment: @VitoSantimone Really.... really..... appreciated! I had tested its many scenario... But no luck. >.<

Comment: I just posted my solution and it works! As you can see i deleted foreach couse i had 2 sites...but with foreach is same thing!

Comment: the problem now is that ajax is perfect! But if i press ENTER no results...normal search is not multisite...any ideas?

Comment: @VitoSantimone will testing your posted solution. And, will check your issue for you.

Comment: @VitoSantimone As my knowledge, the normal search need to go after the search page template with has the pagination function. I will also check your issue at the same time.

Comment: @VitoSantimone Your solution worked for me with my minor changes. Now I am same situation with you (the search page - press ENTER, the normal search is not show multisite), i am digging deep inside to find solution.

Comment: i just posted another question here, with a partial solution https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/367042/woocommerce-multisite-search-archive-php-pagination-problem

Comment: Wow! look like you expert in WooCommerce. ^.^

Comment: @VitoSantimone if you search the noexist keyword or phrase for both site OR either site, would you ajax shown  two (2) "No Product Found" OR shown one (1) "No Product Found"?

Comment: solution is simply!  $blog_id1 = get_current_blog_id();
  
    if ( !$wp_query->have_posts() ) {
      if ($blog_id1==1) { $no1=1; }
      if ($blog_id1==2) { $no2=2; }
    }
//  wp_reset_postdata();

  restore_current_blog();

  endforeach;
  woocommerce_product_loop_end();

  do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
  
  if (($no1==1) & ($no2==2)) { do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' ); }

Comment: @VitoSantimone Thanks! will test it.

Comment: @VitoSantimone try and error few scenario and changes your solution for "if you search the noexist keyword or phrase for both site OR either site, would you ajax shown two (2) "No Product Found" OR shown one (1) "No Product Found". Not worked. Hope you free to check my theme provided file. Which line should I to add your solution (code).

Answer (score 0):

**Answer: Worked ajax search suggestion**

```
/**
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Ajax search
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_init_search_by_sku' ) ) {
    function woodmart_init_search_by_sku() {
        if ( apply_filters( 'woodmart_search_by_sku', woodmart_get_opt( 'search_by_sku' ) ) && woodmart_woocommerce_installed() ) {
            add_filter( 'posts_search', 'woodmart_product_search_sku', 9 );
        }
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'woodmart_init_search_by_sku', 10 );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_ajax_suggestions' ) ) {
    function woodmart_ajax_suggestions() {

        $allowed_types = array( 'post', 'product', 'portfolio' );
        $post_type = 'product';

        if ( apply_filters( 'woodmart_search_by_sku', woodmart_get_opt( 'search_by_sku' ) ) && woodmart_woocommerce_installed() ) {
            add_filter( 'posts_search', 'woodmart_product_ajax_search_sku', 10 );
        }

        $query_args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_type'      => $post_type,
            'no_found_rows'  => 1,
        );

        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) && in_array( $_REQUEST['post_type'], $allowed_types ) ) {
            $post_type = strip_tags( $_REQUEST['post_type'] );
            $query_args['post_type'] = $post_type;
        }

        if ( $post_type == 'product' && woodmart_woocommerce_installed() ) {

            $product_visibility_term_ids = wc_get_product_visibility_term_ids();
            $query_args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                'field'    => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                'terms'    => $product_visibility_term_ids['exclude-from-search'],
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            );

            if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['product_cat'] ) ) {
                $query_args['product_cat'] = strip_tags( $_REQUEST['product_cat'] );
            }
        }

        if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items' ) && $post_type == 'product' ) {
            $query_args['meta_query'][] = array( 'key' => '_stock_status', 'value' => 'outofstock', 'compare' => 'NOT IN' );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['query'] ) ) {
            $query_args['s'] = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['query'] );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['number'] ) ) {
            $query_args['posts_per_page'] = (int) $_REQUEST['number'];
        }

// Blog 1
switch_to_blog(1);

        $results = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woodmart_ajax_search_args', $query_args ) );

        if ( woodmart_get_opt( 'relevanssi_search' ) && function_exists( 'relevanssi_do_query' ) ) {
            relevanssi_do_query( $results );
        }

        $suggestions = array();

        if ( $results->have_posts() ) {

            if ( $post_type == 'product' && woodmart_woocommerce_installed() ) {
                $factory = new WC_Product_Factory();
            }

            while ( $results->have_posts() ) {
                $results->the_post();

                if ( $post_type == 'product' && woodmart_woocommerce_installed() ) {
                    $product = $factory->get_product( get_the_ID() );

                    $suggestions[] = array(
                        'value' => html_entity_decode( get_the_title() ),
                        'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                        'price' => $product->get_price_html(),
                        'thumbnail' => $product->get_image(),
                        'sku' => $product->get_sku() ? esc_html__( 'SKU:', 'woodmart' ) . ' ' . $product->get_sku() : '',
                    );
                } else {
                    $suggestions[] = array(
                        'value' => html_entity_decode( get_the_title() ),
                        'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                        'thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'medium', '' ),
                    );
                }
            }

            wp_reset_postdata();
                restore_current_blog();
        } else {
            $suggestions[] = array(
                'value' => ( $post_type == 'product' ) ? esc_html__( 'No products found', 'woodmart' ) : esc_html__( 'No posts found', 'woodmart' ),
                'no_found' => true,
                'permalink' => ''
            );
        }

// Blog 2
switch_to_blog(2);

        $results = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woodmart_ajax_search_args', $query_args ) );

        if ( woodmart_get_opt( 'relevanssi_search' ) && function_exists( 'relevanssi_do_query' ) ) {
            relevanssi_do_query( $results );
        }

        $suggestions1 = array();

        if ( $results->have_posts() ) {

            if ( $post_type == 'product' && woodmart_woocommerce_installed() ) {
                $factory = new WC_Product_Factory();
            }

            while ( $results->have_posts() ) {
                $results->the_post();

                if ( $post_type == 'product' && woodmart_woocommerce_installed() ) {
                    $product = $factory->get_product( get_the_ID() );

                    $suggestions[] = array(
                        'value' => html_entity_decode( get_the_title() ),
                        'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                        'price' => $product->get_price_html(),
                        'thumbnail' => $product->get_image(),
                        'sku' => $product->get_sku() ? esc_html__( 'SKU:', 'woodmart' ) . ' ' . $product->get_sku() : '',
                    );
                } else {
                    $suggestions[] = array(
                        'value' => html_entity_decode( get_the_title() ),
                        'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                        'thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'medium', '' ),
                    );
                }
            }

            wp_reset_postdata();
                restore_current_blog();
        } else {
            $suggestions[] = array(
                'value' => ( $post_type == 'product' ) ? esc_html__( 'No products found', 'woodmart' ) : esc_html__( 'No posts found', 'woodmart' ),
                'no_found' => true,
                'permalink' => ''
            );
        }

        if ( woodmart_get_opt( 'enqueue_posts_results' ) && 'post' !== $post_type ) {
            $post_suggestions = woodmart_get_post_suggestions();
            $suggestions = array_merge( $suggestions, $suggestion1, $post_suggestions );
        }

            echo json_encode(array('suggestions' => $suggestions
        ));

        die();
    }

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_woodmart_ajax_search', 'woodmart_ajax_suggestions', 10 );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woodmart_ajax_search', 'woodmart_ajax_suggestions', 10 );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_get_post_suggestions' ) ) {
    function woodmart_get_post_suggestions() {
        $query_args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_type'      => 'post',
            'no_found_rows'  => 1,
        );

        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['query'] ) ) {
            $query_args['s'] = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['query'] );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['number'] ) ) {
            $query_args['posts_per_page'] = (int) $_REQUEST['number'];
        }

        $results = new WP_Query( $query_args );
        $suggestions = array();

        if ( $results->have_posts() ) {

            $suggestions[] = array(
                'value' => '',
                'divider' => esc_html__( 'Results from blog', 'woodmart' ),
            );

            while ( $results->have_posts() ) {
                $results->the_post();

                $suggestions[] = array(
                    'value' => html_entity_decode( get_the_title() ),
                    'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                    'thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'medium', '' ),
                );
            }

            wp_reset_postdata();
        }

        return $suggestions;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_product_search_sku' ) ) {
    function woodmart_product_search_sku( $where, $class = false ) {
        global $pagenow, $wpdb, $wp;

        $type = array('product', 'jam');

        if ( ( is_admin() ) //if ((is_admin() && 'edit.php' != $pagenow) 
                || !is_search()  
                || !isset( $wp->query_vars['s'] ) 
                //post_types can also be arrays..
                || (isset( $wp->query_vars['post_type'] ) && 'product' != $wp->query_vars['post_type'] )
                || (isset( $wp->query_vars['post_type'] ) && is_array( $wp->query_vars['post_type'] ) && !in_array( 'product', $wp->query_vars['post_type'] ) ) 
                ) {
            return $where;
        }

        $s = $wp->query_vars['s'];

        //WC 3.6.0
        if ( function_exists( 'WC' ) && version_compare( WC()->version, '3.6.0', '<' ) ) {
            return woodmart_sku_search_query( $where, $s );
        } else {
            return woodmart_sku_search_query_new( $where, $s );
        }
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_product_ajax_search_sku' ) ) {
    function woodmart_product_ajax_search_sku( $where ) {
        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['query'] ) ) {
            $s = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['query'] );

            //WC 3.6.0
            if ( function_exists( 'WC' ) && version_compare( WC()->version, '3.6.0', '<' ) ) {
                return woodmart_sku_search_query( $where, $s );
            } else {
                return woodmart_sku_search_query_new( $where, $s );
            }
        }

        return $where;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_sku_search_query' ) ) {
    function woodmart_sku_search_query( $where, $s ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $search_ids = array();
        $terms = explode( ',', $s );

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            //Include the search by id if admin area.
            if ( is_admin() && is_numeric( $term ) ) {
                $search_ids[] = $term;
            }
            // search for variations with a matching sku and return the parent.

            $sku_to_parent_id = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT p.post_parent as post_id FROM {$wpdb->posts} as p join {$wpdb->postmeta} pm on p.ID = pm.post_id and pm.meta_key='_sku' and pm.meta_value LIKE '%%%s%%' where p.post_parent <> 0 group by p.post_parent", wc_clean( $term ) ) );

            //Search for a regular product that matches the sku.
            $sku_to_id = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value LIKE '%%%s%%';", wc_clean( $term ) ) );

            $search_ids = array_merge( $search_ids, $sku_to_id, $sku_to_parent_id );
        }

        $search_ids = array_filter( array_map( 'absint', $search_ids ) );

        if ( sizeof( $search_ids ) > 0 ) {
            $where = str_replace( ')))', ") OR ({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $search_ids ) . "))))", $where );
        }

        #remove_filters_for_anonymous_class('posts_search', 'WC_Admin_Post_Types', 'product_search', 10);
        return $where;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_sku_search_query_new' ) ) {
    function woodmart_sku_search_query_new( $where, $s ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $search_ids = array();
        $terms = explode( ',', $s );

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            //Include the search by id if admin area.
            if ( is_admin() && is_numeric( $term ) ) {
                $search_ids[] = $term;
            }
            // search for variations with a matching sku and return the parent.

            $sku_to_parent_id = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT p.post_parent as post_id FROM {$wpdb->posts} as p join {$wpdb->wc_product_meta_lookup} ml on p.ID = ml.product_id and ml.sku LIKE '%%%s%%' where p.post_parent <> 0 group by p.post_parent", wc_clean( $term ) ) );

            //Search for a regular product that matches the sku.
            $sku_to_id = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT product_id FROM {$wpdb->wc_product_meta_lookup} WHERE sku LIKE '%%%s%%';", wc_clean( $term ) ) );

            $search_ids = array_merge( $search_ids, $sku_to_id, $sku_to_parent_id );
        }

        $search_ids = array_filter( array_map( 'absint', $search_ids ) );

        if ( sizeof( $search_ids ) > 0 ) {
            $where = str_replace( ')))', ") OR ({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $search_ids ) . "))))", $where );
        }

        #remove_filters_for_anonymous_class('posts_search', 'WC_Admin_Post_Types', 'product_search', 10);
        return $where;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woodmart_rlv_index_variation_skus' ) ) {
    function woodmart_rlv_index_variation_skus( $content, $post ) {
        if ( ! woodmart_get_opt( 'search_by_sku' ) || ! woodmart_get_opt( 'relevanssi_search' ) || ! function_exists( 'relevanssi_do_query' ) ) {
            return $content;
        }

        if ( $post->post_type == 'product' ) {

            $args = array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'product_variation', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
            $variations = get_posts( $args );
            if ( !empty( $variations)) {
                foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
                    $sku = get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_sku', true );
                    $content .= " $sku";
                }
            }
        }

        return $content;
    }

    add_filter( 'relevanssi_content_to_index', 'woodmart_rlv_index_variation_skus', 10, 2 );
}
```