# restore_current_blog() vs. multiple switch_to_blog() followed by removing $GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack']

Tags: multisite, customization

Related to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/123516/16121), which states

> After every instance of `switch_to_blog()` you **need** to call `restore_current_blog()` otherwise WP will think it is in a "switched" mode and can potentially return incorrect data.

I've done some testing, and can confirm that this is an issue.  (It also answers a question I've had at work regarding file upload URLs, so two big thumbs up for that.)

In my testing (detailed below) I found that there were two ways to proceed:

1. Always pair `switch_to_blog()` with `restore_current_blog()`
2. Use a chain of `switch_to_blog()`, with the last one switching back to the blog where you started from, and then `unset( $GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack'] );` at the end.

My question: Is method #2 in keeping with WordPress development best practices, or is it an ugly hack?

#### My Testing

I added the following code to `functions.php` on one of my WordPress Multisite installations:

```
add_action( 'shutdown', 'pj_stb_test' );
function pj_stb_test() {
    if( ! current_user_can( 'update_core' ) )
        return;

    $home = get_current_blog_id();
    $checklist = array(
        'constants' => array( 'UPLOADS', 'MULTISITE', 'BLOGUPLOADDIR' ),
        'functions' => array( 'ms_is_switched', 'wp_upload_dir' ),
    );
    $site_ids = array( 1, 2, 3 );

    echo( "switch_to_blog() chain:<br />" );
    foreach( $site_ids as $id ) {
        switch_to_blog( $id );
    }
    switch_to_blog( $home );
    _pj_dump( $checklist );

    echo( 'switch_to_blog() chain followed by 
           unset( $GLOBALS[\'_wp_switched_stack\'] )<br />' );
    foreach( $site_ids as $id ) {
        switch_to_blog( $id );
    }
    switch_to_blog( $home );
    unset( $GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack'] );
    _pj_dump( $checklist );

    echo( 'switch_to_blog() / restore_current_blog() pairings<br />' );
    foreach( $site_ids as $id ) {
        switch_to_blog( $id );
        restore_current_blog();
    }
    _pj_dump( $checklist );

function _pj_dump( $checklist ) {
    $constants = $checklist['constants'];
    $functions = $checklist['functions'];
    echo( "<p>Constants:</p>" );
    echo( "<pre>\n" );
    foreach( $constants as $c ) {
        echo( $c . ': ' );
        var_dump( constant( $c ) );
        echo( "\n" );
    }
    foreach( $functions as $f ) {
        echo( $f . ': ' );
        var_dump( call_user_func( $f ) );
        echo( "\n" );
    }
}
```

The output that was returned on an arbitrary site in my network:

```
switch_to_blog() chain:
UPLOADS: string(30) "wp-content/blogs.dir/94/files/"
MULTISITE: bool(true)
BLOGUPLOADDIR: string(50) "/path/to/wp/wp-content/blogs.dir/94/files/"
ms_is_switched: bool(true)
wp_upload_dir: array(6) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(57) "/path/to/wp/wp-content/blogs.dir/94/files/2013/11"
  ["url"]=>
  string(74) "http://example.com/my-site/wp-content/blogs.dir/94/files/2013/11"
  ["subdir"]=>
  string(8) "/2013/11"
  ["basedir"]=>
  string(49) "/path/to/wp/wp-content/blogs.dir/94/files"
  ["baseurl"]=>
  string(66) "http://example.com/my-site/wp-content/blogs.dir/94/files"
  ["error"]=>
  bool(false)
} 

switch_to_blog() chain followed by unset( $GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack'] )
UPLOADS: string(30) "wp-content/blogs.dir/94/files/"
MULTISITE: bool(true)
BLOGUPLOADDIR: string(50) "/path/to/wp/wp-content/blogs.dir/94/files/"
ms_is_switched: bool(false)
wp_upload_dir: array(6) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(57) "/path/to/wp/wp-content/blogs.dir/94/files/2013/11"
  ["url"]=>
  string(50) "http://example.com/my-site/files/2013/11"
  ["subdir"]=>
  string(8) "/2013/11"
  ["basedir"]=>
  string(49) "/path/to/wp/wp-content/blogs.dir/94/files"
  ["baseurl"]=>
  string(42) "http://example.com/my-site/files"
  ["error"]=>
  bool(false)
} 

switch_to_blog() / restore_current_blog() pairings
UPLOADS: string(30) "wp-content/blogs.dir/94/files/"
MULTISITE: bool(true)
BLOGUPLOADDIR: string(50) "/path/to/wp/wp-content/blogs.dir/94/files/"
ms_is_switched: bool(false)
wp_upload_dir: array(6) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(57) "/path/to/wp/wp-content/blogs.dir/94/files/2013/11"
  ["url"]=>
  string(50) "http://example.com/my-site/files/2013/11"
  ["subdir"]=>
  string(8) "/2013/11"
  ["basedir"]=>
  string(49) "/path/to/wp/wp-content/blogs.dir/94/files"
  ["baseurl"]=>
  string(42) "http://example.com/my-site/files"
  ["error"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Sorry for the verbosity, but I wanted to make sure I had everything in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is NO.  That is an ugly hack  =)  More global variables are affect than the ones that you are var_dump'ing.    Here are the globals that I found affected: $wpdb, $wp_roles, $wp_object_cache, $global_groups, $GLOBALS['_wp_switched_stack'], $GLOBALS['blog_id'], and $GLOBALS['table_prefix'].  There could be more.  I found that $wpdb was another major variable that was altered by switch_to_blog().  Try var_dump'ing $wpdb in your test and you will see the effect.  Any APIs relying on those globals could be affected if you do not "Always pair switch_to_blog() with restore_current_blog()"

Long answer is "depends on the situation."  I would say the statement "After every instance of switch_to_blog() you need to call restore_current_blog()" is the best practice and generally true.  But there are situations where you do not need to return to the originial blog or do restore_current_blog().  For example, I created an admin plugin which altered a users role across all blogs.  It iterated through all the blogs in the network using switch_to_blog, called other WP APIs (that did not rely on those globals), and ended immediately.  Hence no need to restore_current_blog(). YMMV depending on where and how switch_to_blog() is used.

Comment: As far as your second ¶ goes -- I have a similar situation where I use `switch_to_blog()` repeatedly to generate a network-wide breadcrumb trail, and I think one of the consequences is that `wp_upload_dir()` is returning the full `/wp-content/blogs.dir/[xxx]/files` system path, rather than the `/files` path I expect. So I guess I'll need to add some `restore_current_blog()`s to that code.