# Sort posts according to date

Tags: multisite, get-posts, switch-to-blog

I have problem with sort posts according to date:

My code now:

```
<?php
global $switched;
$original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id(); // get current blog

$blog_ids = array(4,1);

foreach( $blog_ids as $blog_id ){
switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC');
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ):
setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php  endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();

switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id ); //switched back to current blog

restore_current_blog();
}
?>
```

My problem:

http://images.tinypic.pl/i/00700/vracxlcdm296.png

I would like:

http://images.tinypic.pl/i/00700/jo2yp8f83bce.png

I want to sort by date of all blogs.
Not everyone separately.

Comment: And that problem is what...?

Comment: What is **exactly** not happening or happening that should not. Please be specific, as your question stand you will in all propability not get answer :-)

Comment: You have another problem in your code. When you use `switch_to_blog()` you *need* to use `restore_current_blog()` afterward; if you don't, things get messy. See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89113/restore-current-blog-vs-switch-to-blog/123516#123516) and [this Q&A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124064/restore-current-blog-vs-multiple-switch-to-blog-followed-by-removing-globa) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd attack your problem (in fact I think I've written code like this in the past, but I can't find it at the moment):

```
$blogs = array( 4, 1 );
$all_posts = array();
foreach( $blogs as $blog ) {
    switch_to_blog( $blog );
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC');
    $blog_posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $blog_posts as $blog_post ) {
        // Add the correct permalink to the Post object
        $blog_post->permalink = get_the_permalink( $blog_post->ID );
        $all_posts[] = $blog_post;
    }
    restore_current_blog();
}

usort( $all_posts, '__sort_by_date' );

// Now you can display all your posts

foreach( $all_posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title( '<a href="' . $post->permalink . '">', '</a>' );
}


function __sort_by_date( $a, $b ) {
    $a_date = strtotime( $a->post_date );
    $b_date = strtotime( $b->post_date );
    if( $a_date === $b_date ) { return 0; }
    if( $a_date > $b_date ) { return 1; }
    return -1;
}
```

**Note:** I've updated the code to get the correct permalink for each post while we're in the proper site (per your comment/answer below).

### References

- [`usort()`](https://php.net/usort)
- [`strtotime()`](https://php.net/strtotime)
- [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/)
- [`get_the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/)

Comment: You can actually combine the last two lines with the ternary operator (?). It would look like: return ($a_date > $b_date) ? 1 : -1;

Comment: Indeed. I try to keep away from things like `?` if I'm going to be passing my code to (for example) my co-workers, since they're less versed in PHP.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. All working, but it doesn't working `get_the_permalink()`. Problem:

When code is on blog "blog_1", link on to my posts on other blog(name blog: blog_3) is

`"www.name.com/blog_1/2015/09/08/dzfsdsa/"` 

instead

`"www.name.com/blog_3/2015/09/08/dzfsdsa/"`

I change `get_the_permalink()` on `get_the_guid()` and working, but i don't know if I'm doing it well.
z

How safely add blogs in `$blogs = array( 4, 22 );` by sql?

Comment: 1) Are you getting an error message from `get_the_permalink()` in the code?  2) You should be able to simply add blog IDs to the `$blogs` array (eg: `$blogs = array( 4, 22, 19, 27, 1, 42, );` .

Comment: 1. I don't have messages in code about error. Error is only in address for posts. 
Function, add adress `/2015/09/08/name_post/` If i am on website about adress `www.name.com/blog1` I getting adress `www.name.com/blog1/2015/09/08/name_post/` which don't working, because working adress it `www.name.com/blog3/2015/09/08/name_post/` . In short: Correctly reads adress for post, but doesn't blog on which this post is located.

Comment: 2. How correctly and safely reads data with database to table for each user?

Answer (score 0):

You can add argument as below for `get_posts` method

```
'orderby'          => 'date',
'order'            => 'DESC',
```

For more help please visite below link 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts