# Is it possible to query posts with tax queries after multisite switch_to_blog() function?

Tags: multisite, get-posts, tax-query

On my newly installed multisite with 1 installed plugin ACF. And all code below is not being run though any filter or action and on the front end.

On the front end in the `page.php` template, I can successfully `tax_query` posts directly from the current `$site-purchase` blog.

See code below and returned dumps for `get_posts()` and `WP_Query`.

```php
// supplier args
$args = [
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'purchase-supplier',
    'orderby'       => 'title',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'tax_query'     => [
        [
            'taxonomy'  => 'supplier-type',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => 'data-packaging'
        ]
    ]
];

// get supplier posts
$suppliers = get_posts($args);
// $suppliers = WP_Query($args);

dump($suppliers);
```

See `get_posts($args)` results below, which is outputting the correct expected result, post_id 14 (which has `data-packaging` term assigned to it)

```txt
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 14
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2021-03-25 17:17:12
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-03-25 17:17:12
            [post_content] =>
            [post_title] => Another company
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => another-company
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2021-05-26 20:31:25
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2021-05-26 20:31:25
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://localhost/purchase/?post_type=purchase-supplier&p=14
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => purchase-supplier
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

)
```

And here is `new WP_Query($args)` output...

https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/18976d06ce375570fd14ad55d326c9dd

---

However, if I use the exact same code above on `$site_data` blog in the `page.php` template. Using the multisite `switch_to_blog($id)` function to switch too `$site_purchase` to get the data...

```php
// switch to purchase blog
switch_to_blog($site_purchase);

// supplier args
$args = [
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'purchase-supplier',
    'orderby'       => 'title',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'tax_query'     => [
        [
            'taxonomy'  => 'supplier-type',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => 'data-packaging'
        ]
    ]
];

// get supplier posts
$suppliers = get_posts($args);
// $suppliers = WP_Query($args);

dump($suppliers);

// switch back to data blog
switch_to_blog($site_data);
```

Returns empty array via `get_posts($args)`...

```txt
Array
(
)
```

And here is the `new WP_Query($args)` returned output...

https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/42bb619ca289fcbe4ea4e969fe42a1b0

---

But if I modify the php snippet query above used on `$site_data` blog in the `page.php` template. Simply by removing the `tax_query` key value...

```php
// switch to purchase blog
switch_to_blog($site_purchase);

// supplier args
$args = [
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'purchase-supplier',
    'orderby'       => 'title',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
//    'tax_query'     => [
//       [
//            'taxonomy'  => 'supplier-type',
//            'field'     => 'slug',
//            'terms'     => 'data-packaging'
//        ]
//    ]
];

// get supplier posts
$suppliers = get_posts($args);
// $suppliers = WP_Query($args);

dump($suppliers);

// switch back to data blog
switch_to_blog($site_data);
```

The `get_posts($args)` returns expected results. All posts from `purchase-supplier` are outputted in array...

```txt
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 14
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2021-03-25 17:17:12
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-03-25 17:17:12
            [post_content] =>
            [post_title] => Another company
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => another-company
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2021-05-26 20:31:25
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2021-05-26 20:31:25
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://localhost/purchase/?post_type=purchase-supplier&p=14
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => purchase-supplier
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [1] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 131
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2021-05-20 21:15:56
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-05-20 21:15:56
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => Barry Callebaut
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => barry-callebaut
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2021-05-25 23:12:05
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2021-05-25 23:12:05
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://localhost/purchase/?post_type=purchase-supplier&p=131
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => purchase-supplier
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [2] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 12
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2021-03-20 22:53:51
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-03-20 22:53:51
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => Hancock Cash & Carry Ltd
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => hancock-cash-carry-ltd
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2021-05-26 14:54:08
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2021-05-26 14:54:08
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://localhost/purchase/?post_type=supplier&p=12
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => purchase-supplier
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [3] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 13
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2021-03-25 16:53:18
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-03-25 16:53:18
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => Test
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => test
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2021-05-25 23:12:14
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2021-05-25 23:12:14
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://localhost/purchase/?post_type=purchase-supplier&p=13
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => purchase-supplier
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

)
```

And here is the `new WP_Query($args)` returned output on `$site-data` without `tax_query`...

https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/6df8c87f789564d64892b675c8a18a7f

---

Just cant get my head round why `tax_query` is failing in the `switch_to_blog()` function when all other tests show `tax_query` works on current `$site_purchase` blog, and the basic query (without `tax_query`) also works fine returning all `purchase-supplier` posts from `$site_purchase` blog within `$site_data` blog.

But as soon as I add my `tax_query` to my query args on `$site_data`, no `purchase-supplier` posts (id 14) are returned. Only an empty array is returned. Weird!

Any ideas? Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely possible. So if you're certain the exact same query args work when running the query within the `$site_purchase` site, then try deactivating plugins and see if the issue persists. But, in what template/file is the code in question placed and on what page/URL does it run?

Comment: If you are certain it is possible, and you seem to grasp my initial question well. Let me add a bit more detail on usage to my question. I can't imagine it is a plugin conflict as I am only running ACF at the mo, it is in very early stages of development this theme.

Comment: On a completely fresh install of WordPress + Multisite, yes I am certain the taxonomy queries will work. So try with `$suppliers = new WP_Query( $args ); var_dump( $suppliers->request );` and share the dump output (the generated SQL) or just check if it's good. And, "outputted in `$site_data` blog admin, coded in the `functions.php` (same as example 2)" - okay, but on what page exactly (there are many admin pages, right?) and inside what hook?

Comment: @SallyCJ rewrote question with simplest usage examples and returned outputs including WP_Query returned full outputs in gists. Thanks for taking the time to check this out for me.

Comment: Every time you use `switch_to_blog()`, you *have* to use `restore_current_blog()` to switch back to your original site. Chaining multiple `switch_to_blog()`s will have unexpected consequences. See [this Q&A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124064/restore-current-blog-vs-multiple-switch-to-blog-followed-by-removing-globa) for some details.

Comment: OK cool thanks @PatJ, let me check it out. This is great thing to know as I was using `switch_to_blog()` also switch back to the initial blog.

Comment: I don't think that's your actual problem, but it might cause you grief later. Best to catch it now.

Comment: Also: where are the post type and the taxonomy defined? If it's in the theme, is the theme active on both sites in question? If it's a plugin, is the plugin activated in both sites (or network-wide)?

Comment: @PatJ, single theme for all sites and using conditional logic to check if site is site and then registering types/taxes. But you raise a super valid point... Querying custom post types might not actually require `register_post_type` to be envoked, but `tax_queries` might actually need to understand the taxonomy is registered, in order to tax query... which in my situation, the tax is only registered on the purchase site, not the data site. I can't imagine the `switch_to_blog()` function reloads the entire theme functions prior to my query. This could be the issue. I will test it out thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry @joshmoto, I actually had the taxonomy registered on all my test sites. So as you could see from the `$suppliers->request` output, it contains `WHERE 1=1  AND ( 0 = 1 )` which means the taxonomy is not registered. Therefore, as stated in my answer (and as you've already figured it out now), the taxonomy needs to be registered in both the sites in question (`$site_purchase` and `$site_data`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you will need to register the taxonomy on both sites because [`switch_to_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/) does not register the taxonomy for you, it mainly only switches the database and yet, taxonomies are not stored in the database, only the terms in the taxonomies.

But you don't have to register the taxonomy on page load.. (but yes, that's the proper way to do it). Because as long as it is registered, then the `tax_query` will work. And here's an example to register the `supplier-type` taxonomy right **after** you call `switch_to_blog()`:

```php
// switch to purchase blog
switch_to_blog($site_purchase);

// Register the taxonomy.
$taxonomy = 'supplier-type';
if ( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ) {
    register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, null, [] );
    // or call your custom function which registers the taxonomy using the proper args
}

// ... your code.
```

[Edit] I gave the above example because (in the comments) you said, "*using conditional logic to check if site is site and then registering types/taxes*" and also "*the tax is only registered on the purchase site, not the data site*". So the above should work even if you conditionally registered the taxonomy.

Also, in response to "*Querying custom post types might not actually require `register_post_type` to be envoked, but `tax_queries` might actually need to understand the taxonomy is registered*", yes that's correct.

More specifically, the tax query [class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/) uses [`taxonomy_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/taxonomy_exists/) when generating the SQL statement (`JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses) for the tax query's clauses (see [source on Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-tax-query.php#L396)), and when the specified taxonomy is not registered, then the `WHERE` clause will be `0 = 1` (as in `WHERE 1=1  AND ( 0 = 1 ) AND tsp_2_posts.post_type = 'purchase-supplier' ...`) just as you could see in the `$suppliers->request` value [here](https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/42bb619ca289fcbe4ea4e969fe42a1b0). Hence, that explains the empty posts array or the "*why `tax_query` is failing in the `switch_to_blog()` function*".

*So make sure the taxonomies used in your tax queries are properly registered.* And despite `WP_Query` doesn't check if a post type exists (e.g. using `post_type_exists()`) when querying for posts in custom post types, if after switching to any site you need to get the post type object or data (e.g. using `get_post_type_object()`), then make sure the post type is registered correctly.

Comment: Thank you @SallyCJ for your help on this. This was exactly the issue. Makes sense now. Thanks for your detailed answer to close this problem. +1