# List all sites in multisite

Tags: multisite, list

I want to list all sites in the multi site network in alphabetical order? Right now, the code lists by registered date

```
<?php
// Query for getting blogs
            $blogs = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT blog_id, domain, path FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE site_id = %d AND public = '1' AND archived = '0' AND mature = '0' AND spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' ORDER BY registered DESC", $wpdb->siteid), ARRAY_A );

            // put it in array  
            foreach ( (array) $blogs as $details ) {$blog_list[ $details['blog_id'] ] = $details;}
            unset( $blogs );
            $blogs = $blog_list;

            // if is valid array
            if (is_array( $blogs ) ){
                    echo '<ul>';
                    $array= array();
                    // reorder
                    $array= array_slice( $blogs, 0, count( $blogs ) );
                    for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
                    // get data for each id
                    $blog = get_blog_details( $array[$i]['blog_id'] );
                    // print it
                    echo '<li><a href="'.$blog->siteurl.'">'.$blog->blogname.'</a></li>';
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can try to replace:

```
ORDER BY registered DESC
```

with:

```
ORDER BY domain ASC, path ASC
```

to get the sites in an alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the sites by their site name, and not by their path, use [`strcasecmp()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) in a callback for [`uasort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).

Example

```
is_admin() || add_action( 'shutdown', function() {

    $sites = wp_get_sites();

    foreach ( $sites as $i => $site ) {

        switch_to_blog( $site[ 'blog_id' ] );
        $sites[ $i ][ 'name' ] = get_bloginfo();
        restore_current_blog();
    }

    uasort( $sites, function( $site_a, $site_b ) {
        return strcasecmp( $site_a[ 'name' ], $site_b[ 'name' ] );
    });

    print '<pre>' . print_r( $sites, 1 ) . '</pre>';
});
```

Comment: Good idea (+1). I wonder if we need `restore_current_blog()` inside the foreach loop? Isn't it enough to have it after the loop?

Comment: @birgire [Not necessary](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/89114/73).