# Count posts on multisite with blog id

Tags: php, posts, multisite

How would I use a blog/site id to count posts from the id specified site much like [`wp_count_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts) does for the current site?

I'm trying to create a function for an AJAX accessed endpoint where a user can select a site from a `select` element to see how many posts there are on other sites.

I **really** want to stay away from querying the database directly.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `wp_count_posts()` as you would on a single site, pass the blog id into the [`switch_to_blog()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) function before calling `wp_count_posts()`.

Example:

```
function wpse_get_post_count( $blog_id ){
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    $post_count = wp_count_posts();
    restore_current_blog();
    return $post_count;
}
```

Ensure `restore_current_blog()` is used after every `switch_to_blog()` or you will risk difficulties mentioned in the [notes section of the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog#Notes) and this [WordPress Stack Exchange answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/123516/64943).

Comment: Don't you need to restore_current_blog() after you switch? So maybe store the value in a variable and then return it after you restore the current blog.

Comment: @Nikolay There doesn't seem to be a reason to  restore the "current" blog in this case, but once/if I find one, I will update my answer.

Comment: It says here in the notes section that "restore_current_blog() should be called after every switch_to_blog()": https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog

Comment: Thank you for that @Nikolay, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Cool, no problem :)