# Loop (iterate) through Multi-Site sub-sites (blogs)?

Tags: functions, multisite

What is the easiest approach to iterate through the sub-sites (in Multi-Site network) and let's say `add_option("xyz", 123)` for each of site.

Comment: See also: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89113/restore-current-blog-vs-switch-to-blog

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can get sites with [`get_sites`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/) and loop through them:

```
if ( function_exists( 'get_sites' ) && class_exists( 'WP_Site_Query' ) ) {
    $sites = get_sites();
    foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
        // do something
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found this so far to work for me:

```
foreach (get_sites() as $blog){
    switch_to_blog($blog->blog_id);
    // get_option (...)   
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that you use `switch_to_blog` which is very very bad for performance... And you don't need it to set option...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż forget the "get_option". what are alternatives for itteration then without `switch_to_blog` ? So loop could be used.